# Synthesis and Transformation

Tags: grammar, writing-style, paraphrasing

Give the task of synthesizing and transforming these two sentences:

> 1. John ran after the snatch thief.
> 2. John tripped over a stone and fell.

Into just one of this form:

> 3. While ____________, ____________.

The provided choices were:

> **Answer 1:**
>  While running after the snatch thief, John tripped over a stone and fell.

> **Answer 2:**
>  While John was running after the snatch thief, he tripped over a stone and fell.

My students are often confused as to how to synthesise and transform those two sentences. My explanation is to identify the main clause. So Answer 1 is correct.

Is there a better explanation?

Comment: Both answers are equally correct; there is no rule of "correctness" here. Either clause can function as the main clause; it depends on what the speaker wants to stress, and where they want to put it in the sentence.

Comment: Stylewise, I'd prefer 'as' here. Yes, the pursuit is durative, but the trip is punctive.

Comment: //While running after the snatch thief, John tripped over a stone and fell.// Of the two, this is the correct one.  This is a single-clause sentence; hence there is no question of main clause or dependent clause. "While running after the snatch thief" is a phrase; not a clause. It can make sense even without 'while', like "Running after the snatch thief, John tripped over a stone and fell."

Comment: A great deal of damage is done to the students of a language when such subtle matters of style are forced into a multiple-choice, correct-or-incorrect format.

Comment: And even: John ran after the snatch thief. tripped over a stone and fell. Why bother with "while".

Comment: In (2) it's unclear who tripped.

Comment: Yes, both are correct, but #1 is more efficient (less words to say the same thing). Identifying what should be the main clause when combining two sentences is key. With these two sentences, causality is also a clue: the tripping and falling could not precede the running.

Comment: << John ran after the snatch thief; he tripped over a stone and fell. >> Take your pick of independent clauses.

Comment: Looking up the terms 'synthesise' and 'transform' on various websites, I'm not sure the latter at least has an agreed definition. Some sites seem to license any correct paraphrasing. Using a contrastive coordinator << John ran after the snatch thief, but he tripped over a stone and fell. >> is one way to use fewer full stops. But I'd prefer a more staccato style here. Optimal rephrasing and question constraints are imo at odds.

Answer (score 0):

From a pure English perspective, they are both correct. However, the first one will typically be considered better writing. This is because “While” is a phrase that modifies John, the noun. The second sentence is poorly constructed because the modifier is wordy relative to what is possible. In other words, it’s a poor use of a modifying clause/needlessly verbose.

Comment: I disagree. (2) introduces the agent earlier in the narrative. This may be the preferred choice, depending on context. And while (1) is, I agree, more stylish, this could grade into pretentiousness ... and in fact, there may be better ways of writing the contents of (1) and (2). // Yes, this doesn't stick within the constraints of the test question. But ELU usually dismisses local terminologies and artificial (especially sub-optimal) constraints.